# No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"" - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the below error and unsure how to correct it - your help would be much appreciated.

when at a users show page, i do not get the error, but when at for example at any other page...such as the events index.html page the error displays

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"friendships", :friend_id=>#<User id: 5, email: "ian@gmail.com"
```

expanded error in terminal

```
Started GET "/events" for ::1 at 2016-12-17 12:44:43 +0000
Processing by EventsController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Subscription Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."title" = ? LIMIT 1  [["title", "premium"]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = ? AND "friendships"."status" = ?  [["user_id", 4], ["status", "requested"]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = ? AND "friendships"."status" = ?  [["user_id", 4], ["status", "requested"]]
  Rendered shared/_content_dropdownbox_friendrequest.html.erb (4.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (10.7ms)
  Rendered events/index.html.erb within layouts/application (11.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms

ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"friendships", :friend_id=>#<User id: 5, email: "ian@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$PMO5FPBzjjnFHI/ye8rfP.ONtHP3gagXomj1sbruBXH..."
```

route file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :friendships,   only: [:create, :update, :destroy]

  devise_for :users
  resources :users
end
```

views/shared/_content_dropdownbox_friendrequest.html.erb

```
<ul>
  <% current_user.requested_friends.each do |requester| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to(image_tag(requester.image_url, :alt =>  "image", :class =>"#", id: ""), user_path(requester)) %>
      <%= link_to truncate("#{requester.firstname} #{requester.lastname}", length: 23), user_path(requester) %>
      <%= link_to 'Accept', friendship_path(user_id: current_user, friend_id: requester), controller: "friendships", action: "update", method: :put %>
      <%= link_to 'Decline', friendship_path(user_id: current_user, friend_id: requester), controller: "friendships", action: "decline", method: :delete %>
    </li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

frienships_controller

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :setup_friends

  # Sends a friend request.
  # We'd rather call this "request", but that's not allowed by Rails.
  def create
    Friendship.request(@user, @friend)
    flash[:notice] = "Request sent."
    redirect_to :back
  end

  # Accepts a friend request.
  # We'd rather call this "accept", but that's not allowed by Rails.
  def update
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:user_id])
    @friend = User.friendly.find(params[:friend_id])
    if @user.requested_friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.accept(@user, @friend)
      flash[:notice] = "Connection with #{@friend.firstname} accepted!"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "No connect request from #{@friend.firstname}."
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:user_id])
    @friend = User.friendly.find(params[:friend_id])
    if @user.requested_friends.include?(@friend) #decline
      Friendship.breakup(@user, @friend)
      redirect_to :back
    elsif @user.pending_friends.include?(@friend) #cancel
      Friendship.breakup(@user, @friend)
      redirect_to :back
    elsif @user.friends.include?(@friend) #delete
      Friendship.breakup(@user, @friend)
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  private
  def setup_friends
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @friend = User.find_by_email(params[:id])
  end
end
```

i am unsure how to solve the error, i tried something like the below but does not work:

```
<span>
  <%= form_for friendship, url: friendship_path(requester), method: :put do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :friend_id, value: requester.id %>
    <%= submit_tag "Accept_test", controller: "friendships", action: "update", class: "btn btn_add_friend" %>
  <% end %>
</span>
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind your set-up. You're already creating the friendship in the create method right? So whenever the receiver accepts or declines, you only need to update the 'accepted' (or whatever you named it) value of the friendship record right? No need to be passing all kinds of IDs around, only the ID of the friendship record is enough to do all transactions. This is in my opinion bad practice from a Rails perspective.

Answer (score 4):

update controller is waiting for an `id` parameter, while the only parameters you pass are `user_id` and `friend_id`.

You can change your routes to the following

```
resources :friendships,   only: [:create, :destroy] do
  collection do
    put :update
  end
end
```